# close chrome notification on click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, web-push, web-notifications

I'm trying to create web notifications via chrome
and I'm receiving the notification and it's working fine
the problem is when I'm clicking on the notification it is not disappearing
please help me in closing notification when clicked/opened

I currently have

```js
let dnperm = document.getElementById("dnperm");
let dntrigger = document.getElementById("dntrigger");

dnperm.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if(!window.Notification) {
    alert("Sorry, Notifications are not supported!");
  } else {
    Notification.requestPermission(function(p) {
      if (p === "denied") {
        alert("You Denied");
      } else if (p === "granted") {
        alert("You Allowed");
      }
    });
  }
});

dntrigger.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let notify;
  e.preventDefault();
  if (Notification.permission ==="default") {
    alert("Allow Notifications First!");
  } else {
    notify = new Notification("New Message!", {
                      "body": "Hello",
                      "icon": "favicon.png",
                      "tag": "123456",
                      "image": "img/legendary.jpg",
    });

    notify.onclick = function() {
      window.location = "https://www.google.com/";
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="dnperm">Notifications</a>
<a href="#" id="dntrigger">Trigger</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [`Notification.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/close).

On the `.onclick`, just run `notify.close()`

```
notify.onclick = function() {
  window.location = "https://www.google.com/";
  notify.close();
};
```